# ReferenceError can't find variable flatlist and Element Type Invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was following tutorial and I got 'ReferenceError can't find variable flatlist' error, then I deleted the code and copied from the github to check if I might missed something and it's still didn't work.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import  {StyleSheet, Text, View,FlatList}  from 'react-native';
import Header from './components/header';




export default function App () {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
    { text: 'buy coffee', key: '1' },
    { text: 'create an app', key: '2' },
    { text: 'play on the switch', key: '3' }
  ]);
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Header />
      <View style={styles.content}>
        {/* add todo form */}
        <View style={styles.list}>
          <FlatList
            data={todos}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
              <Text>{item.text}</Text>
            )}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  content:{
    padding: 40,
   },
  list:{
    marginTop:20,
  } 
});
```

Header :

```
import React from 'react';
import  {StyleSheet, Text, View}  from 'react-native';


export default function Header() {
    return(
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>My Todo List</Text>
        </View>
    )

}

const styles= StyleSheet.create({
    header:{
        height: 80,
        paddingTop: 38,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
    title:{
        textAlign: 'center',
        color:'#fff',
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight:'bold',
    }

});

export default Header;
```

Perhaps something changed in the version or something else. I will be grateful if you can tell how I can fix the error.

Edit: I changed the casing from Flatlist to FlatList and I got error 'Element type invalid: expected a string (for built- in components)'.
[\ Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L7iQ.png)

Comment: check your casing: `Flatlist` and `FlatList` are different variables

Comment: I got  another error ' Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)

Comment: Hard to help with errors like *"Element type is invalid"* when you don't specify where exactly they are thrown

Comment: I included the Screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change case of Flatlist import as:

```
import  {StyleSheet, Text, View,FlatList}  from 'react-native';
```

check export of your header component. You have exported Header Component two time.

Comment: Thank you so much! Even with keeping useState the app has worked

Answer (score 0):

Try Replace `Flatlist` with `FlatList`

Correct: `import  {StyleSheet, Text, View,FlatList}  from 'react-native';`

Also, try to export as Class, if it's entry point:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    todos: [
      { text: 'buy coffee', key: '1' },
      { text: 'create an app', key: '2' },
      { text: 'play on the switch', key: '3' },
    ],
  };

  render() {
    const { todos } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header />
        <View style={styles.content}>
          {/* add todo form */}
          <View style={styles.list}>
            <FlatList
              data={todos}
              renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.text}</Text>}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work I got another error ' Element type is invalid:expected a string'

Comment: The screenshot is provided

Comment: Error line 16, check your <Header/>

Comment: Same Error https://paste.pics/1aa08b05b83a0cfb378a1f943f692401